# Deny access to all the content of a section of website with Nginx from Plesk

Tags: nginx, plesk

I need to deny access to a part of website and allow some IP Addresses to access it for example my site is `example.com` it is accessible by every one but `example.com/test` and all its files are accessible only for `123.123.123.123`, so I tried this code in PLESK.

Domains > example.com >Apache & nginx Settings. In the Additional nginx directives section I added this code and my IP address.

Code:

```
location ^~ /test {
allow 203.0.113.2;
deny all;
}
```

this worked for `example.com/test` but for `example.com/test/file.php` it did not work the files are accessible, and they are being downloaded instead of being executed, I Googled for solution but I did not find anything so what should I add to fix this and to deny access to all the content of `/test` 
because I  need to upload an angular project in this directory that I want to limit access to, so I need to deny access to different directories and different file formats.